# Can dragons use Unihorns to heal themselves?

Tags: nethack

My character has a couple of dragons, each has a unihorn. I'm almost ready to polypile, and 2 more magic tools wouldn't hurt.  I have a bullwhip, so taking them shouldn't be a problem.  But, if the dragons actually use them, I'd prefer they keep them. So, can dragons use unihorns to heal themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Any monster with hands that is in possession of a non-cursed unicorn horn (or one with an unknown BUC status) will use it to cure blindness, stunning, or confusion.  Your pet dragons don't have hands, so they won't use the unicorn horns.